# Can file size be used to detect a partial append?

Tags: linux, unix, file-io, filesystems, posix

I'm thinking about ways for my application to detect a partially-written record after a program or OS crash. Since records are only ever **appended** to a file (never overwritten), is a crash while writing guaranteed to yield a file size that is shorter than it should be? Is this guaranteed even if the file was opened in read-write mode instead of append mode, so long as writes are always at the end of the file? This would greatly simplify crash recovery, since comparing the last record's expected size and position with the actual file size would be enough to detect a partial write.

I understand that random-access writes can be reordered by the filesystem, but I'm having trouble finding information on whether this can happen when appending.  I imagine an out-of-order append would require the filesystem to create a "hole" at the tail of the (sparse) file, write blocks beyond the hole, and then fill in the blocks in between, but I'm hoping that such an approach would be so inefficient that nobody would ever implement their filesystem that way.

I suppose another problem might be a filesystem updating the directory entry's file size field before appending the new blocks to to the file, and the OS crashing in between. Does this ever happen in practice? (ext4, perhaps?) Is there a quick way to detect it? (And what happens when trying to read the unwritten blocks that should exist according to the file's size?)

Is there anything else, such as write reordering performed by a disk/flash drive, that would get in the way of using file size as a way to detect a partial append? I don't expect to be able to compensate for this sort of drive trickery in my application, but it would be good to know about.

Comment: Why don't you simply backup the "record" file before appending? and delete it after the appending ends or the program exit correctly? That's way better than checking file size.

Comment: Because a record could in some cases be gigabytes in size. I'm trying to avoid unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be SURE that you're never going to lose records, you need a consistent journaling or transactional system for your files.

There is absolutely no guarantee that a write will have been fulfilled unless you either set O_DIRECT [which you probably do not want to do], or you use markers to indicate aht "this has been fully committed", that are only written when the file is closed. You can either do that in the mainfile, or, for example, have a file that records, externally, "last written record". If you open & close that file, it should be safe as long as the APP is what is crashing - if the OS crashes [or is otherwise abruptly stopped - e.g. power cut, disk unplugged, etc], all bets are off.

Write reordering and write caching is/can be done at all levels - the C library, the OS, the filesystem module and the hard disk/controller itself are all ABLE to reorder writes.

Comment: I don't need a guarantee that record writes have been fulfilled; I'm just looking for a way to tell when they haven't. (The goal is to avoid file corruption, not to ensure that no record is ever lost.)
Regarding your marker suggestion, I intend to save the last-written record's location and size in a separate (small) file, using the newfile/sync/rename idiom to keep it atomic. But that's only useful if I can detect when the main data file isn't the size that it should be.

Comment: First, what I meant by "guarantee they have been fulfilled" is exactly what you describe - a way to tell what has been written. Of course, if you record "I've written 1234 records", and your file is only 1230 records long, then clearly, some records whent missing. You can also detect that the "app didn't close properly" by having a temporary "marker-file", that gets deleted/renamed when you clsoe the app properly.

Comment: Your "marker-file" idea will clearly work if the filesystem performs operations in the order the application requests them. However, sometimes things don't work that way. For example, the ext4 filesystem (until it was patched with new default behavior) had a habit of renaming files before it had fulfilled previous writes, resulting in 0-byte files replacing perfectly good ones when a crash occurred at a bad time.

Comment: Right, BROKEN filesystem behaviour is rather hard to fix in any other code than the actual filesystem. I don't think if you have closed the file in the application, you SHOULD be able to get filedata lost [unless the OS crashes, again, something an application won't be able to guard usefully against].

Comment: ...which is why I need a more reliable way to detect when the data file has an incomplete record. Obviously an unexpectedly short file would indicate an incomplete append. My question is whether I can **rely** on the file to be short when there was an incomplete append.

Comment: No, technically, the filesystem can extend the file [as in, write the size to the directory data] first, then fill in the data within the block. So, in a word, no.

Comment: Can you link any references to filesystems that do this in practice, or to what happens when attempting to read blocks that are within the reported size but were never written?

Comment: No, I don't have a reference to this, but I have seen it with my own eyes. The file had all zeros where I expected data to be. Of course, I don't know for sure if it was a bug or "expected behaviour". I would say a well behaved, healthy system wouldn't do this. This is why people who run reliable systems use kernels that are 3-4 years old and only apply really necessary patches!

Comment: Okay, so a partial append can result in either an unexpectedly short file size or (if meta-data was written before data) one with a bunch of 0x00 bytes where data should be. The latter case could be detected by checking for a marker at the end of each record, **if** append operations are always written to disk in order. (that is, without holes.) Are they?